# Xamarin.Forms iOS build error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I currently created a new Xamarin.Forms project using VS 2019 in my PC, installed some nuget packages and after building the project I got the following error from the iOS project.

> .nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.10.0\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(52,3): error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I checked the Error log file attached to my repo folder on my PC I saw the error:

```
Date:2021-07-02 07:10:23,580
Thread:[1]
Level:ERROR
Logger:Syncfusion.Xamarin.UI.MainViewModel                         [(null)]
Message:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Syncfusion.Xamarin.UI.MainWindow.ItemCheckBox_Unchecked(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Also, I have done a lot builds, rebuild, clean solution, restore nuget, and I had to uninstall the prelease versions of the nuget packages and installed the latest stable versions yet nothing changed.

Comment: From the error log, you can recheck  the relative code in your app `ItemCheckBox_Unchecked` .You are trying to use something that is null . This means you either set it to null, or you never set it to anything at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying @JessieZhang-MSFT I had to uninstall two nuget packages (plugin.googleclient and plugin.Facebook) and everything came back to normal. However, I don't know why it should be so.